# Travelling with a portable Stove and fuel canisters

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, legal, airport-security, prohibited-items

I am planning to order a portable stove and the fuel canisters (may or may not be empty) from US.
Reason of not having it shipped to India is: [The particular product](https://www.rei.com/product/890802/msr-windburner-stove-system) I am looking forward to purchase is not available in India, the vendor is in US and is not game for shipping it to India. The other vendor is costing the same item substantial amount for shipping in India, so I don't think its a good deal for me.

So, I am planning to ask one of my friends who is travelling from US to India on business/non-tourist purpose.

Should that be problem if he has a valid invoice of the item and its packed neat, probably as received?

Comment: Having a very quick look - I think fuel will be a no go area. Stoves will probably depend on your airline and airports. Will post a proper answer later, do any of these links help - http://www.airindia.in/baggage-tips-and-restricted-items.htm

Comment: https://india.visahq.com/customs/

Comment: Given that India has tons of stoves, what's so special about this kind / model that you want to get it all the way from the US. Curious :)

Comment: @AlexS: Hi, Sorry, I thought that it would be unnecessary to share the link to the product. Stoves like MSR are not sold in India upfront. These are very portable and not available in India.

Comment: @WedaPashi - If you post a picture of the TYPE of stove, not necessarily to a specific brands/ companys product that would help us as well and other users of the site in future who may be thinking like you for portable items like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most if not all airlines prohibit carrying fuel canisters onboard, both as checked and as carry-on luggage. It is a compressed canister containing flammable liquid. [The TSA page on prohibited items confirms this.](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/prohibited-items)  So flying from the US with the fuel canister is definitely a no, regardless of whether it can be imported in India.

The stove without fuel should be allowed in your checked in luggage. Without fuel the stove is harmless but could still be construed as a dangerous sharp if placed in your carry-on. At this point you'll have to look up Indian custom duties on stoves to see how much it'll cost.